# Failed to get the adb version

Tags: android

while running sample android project getting this error on eclipse.. project cleaned 2-3 times but still getting error.

```
[2012-10-23 10:39:24 - adb] Failed to get the adb version: Cannot run program
"/home/rahul/android-sdks/platform-tools/adb": error=13, Permission denied from    
'/home/rahul/android-sdks/platform-tools/adb' - exists=true
```

Comment: did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

#### You must add the paths of platform-tools and tools folder to the .bashrc file.

```
sudo gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Add the following lines at the bottom,

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/rahul/android-sdks/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:/home/rahul/android-sdks/tools
```

#### You must also add java path to the .bashrc file,

```
cd /usr/lib/jvm
ls
```

In my case,it appears like this

```
avinash@avinash-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z500:/usr/lib/jvm$ ls
java-7-oracle
```

so add below lines to the .bashrc file,

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME
```

#### Note,

java-7-oracle folder(in mycase) inside `/usr/lib/jvm` only appears if you installed java on your Ubuntu pc.To check java installed on your pc run `java -version` command.If the output like this,

```
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

shows you installed java.If not try to install it.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions provided here helped, but I still couldn't run adb.  Same problem on the command prompt as in Eclipse.  I found this article by Markus Bertheau and it now runs:  http://www.markusbe.com/2009/09/about-running-32-bit-programs-on-64-bit-ubuntu-and-shared-libraries

The key was to install two additional programs because I'm on a 64-bit machine and SDK runs 32-bit libraries - libc6-i386 and ia32-libs.  After installing them, I can run adb!

Thank you Markus Bertheau!